# No Option to Add Column in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, cpanel

I have no option to add a new column to a table in PHPMyAdmin

User has all Privileges granted - but apart from that I have trawled net for an answer and cannot find a thing.

Hope you can shed some light on something that is most likely very simple.

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/uogb69r3z/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is just in the wrong part of phpMyAdmin.

Comment: So would it not of been more helpful to show me the correct part? Thanks...

Comment: Someone already had, as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot shows that you are on the Browse page. Click on Structure to see the "Add x column" dialog.

Comment: That was it - told you it would be something simple, thank you - saved my hair!